# Is there a way to alias input names in the rules for Laravel 5 validation?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-5

I like the feature in Laravel 5 that let's me throw my validation logic into one of Laravel 5's Form Requests and then [Laravel will automatically validate it just before](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation) my controller's method is ran. However, one thing that is missing is an easy way to "alias" an input name.

For example (for simplicity sake), say I have a login form with an input field called "username" but it actually accepts an email address. The label on my form says *Email*. If there's an error, the error will say something like "Username is required". This is confusing since I'm labeling the field as *Email* on my form.

**What's a good solution for aliasing inputs when using Laravel's validator?**

So far I've come up with two ideas:

**Solution 1:**  Use Laravel's custom error messages for each rule

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AuthLoginRequest extends Request {

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'username' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required'
        ];
    }

    // This is redundant. And may have other pitfalls?
    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'username.required' => 'email is required.',
            'username.email' => 'email is invalid.'
        ];
    }

    ...
}
```

**Solution 2:** Use my own custom form class to handle changing the input names to their label/alias (*username* becomes *email* for validation purposes), running validation, then changing them back.

Comment: I don’t know about you, but I tend to favour naming my fields after the data they accept. If it’s a username, I’ll label it as such. If it’s an email address, same deal.

Comment: @MartinBean that's a simple example. But after you've done all the work and a stakeholder says "That label won't make sense to our end-users" then you are in trouble.

Comment: `$ php artisan make:migration rename_username_to_email`

Comment: I wouldn't say that's how you respond to a superficial demand.

Comment: If they have a valid point. If users authenticate via email address, then I’d name the field `email` and not `username`.

Comment: I guess you are looking for a better example then. In the US they are called "fries", but in the UK they are called "chips". Now what will you do?

Comment: Use Laravel’s localization component and create translations for `en_GB` and `en_US`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what one of the answers is suggesting. However many contexts won't have anything to do with translations or nationality. Another example is sports, where some say games, and other sports use the term matches.

Answer (score 10):

`

```
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class AuthLoginRequest extends Request {

public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required'
    ];
}

public function messages()
{
    return [
        'username.required' => ':attribute is required',
        'username.email' => ':attribute is invalid'
    ];
}

public function attributes()
{
    return[
        'username' => 'email', //This will replace any instance of 'username' in validation messages with 'email'
        //'anyinput' => 'Nice Name',
    ];

}
```

}`

**Updated**

I believe anywhere there's an `:attribute` in your messages will be either default to the name set in your form, or overridden by the method `attributes()` above. (on `:attribute` http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-error-messages)

Footnote: I have not explained how I'm doing a dynamic array for my form, as I'm iterating over each form input in a way which may be clumsy. I did notice that I'm using the following line for my form request. I thought I'd mention that here in case:

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
```

Let me know if this is more helpful!

Comment: Can you give a more complete example (doesn't have to be a large form, but use the example I gave in my question if you want)? You've commented out 2 sections and your example still leaves me the duty of having to go into the laravel codebase just to understand it. I think your solution is probably the correct solution here, just need to see it in completion. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidGraham Expanded to include your example, hopefully this helps you. It was a late night for me!

Comment: A note for myself: The documentation about it [is here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-error-messages). `:attribute`,`:max`,`:min`,`:size`,`:values`

Answer (score 4):

You can customise your validation input names in file resources/lang/en/validation.php, assuming you are using Laravel 5 and using English as locale language by default.

You can find an array called 'custom', simply customise your input names and validation messages there.

For example:

```
'custom' => array(
    'username' => array(
        'email' => 'Username is actually an email.'
    ),
)
```

where 'username' is your input name, 'email' is the name of built-in rule, and 'Username is actually an email' is whatever you want to tell your user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 This is a great solution for when I know globally that an input will be aliased throughout the whole app! But it won't work for a diverse range of forms where I use all kinds of labels that differ from my input names.

Comment: Is it possible to keep labels consistent with input names?

Answer (score 2):

Open the file resources/lang/en/validation.php, where en is the default language of the app. thars if you are using English. At the bottom of the file, update the attributes array as the following:

```
'attributes' => array( 'password' => 'Password', 'email' => 'Email Address', ),
```

Add other attribute names and the corresponding error label. It will do the trick you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($data, [
    'username' => 'required|string', // Your field validation
])
->setAttributeNames(
    ['username' => '"Username"'], // Your field name and alias
);
```